Images not showing on react-slick slider
My images are not showing on the slider only the captions are showing. The slider is working well, the captions are all showing but the images are not showing. I have tried to import images in different ways including using network images but the images do not show. Please help
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import banner from "../assets/banner.png";
import img2 from "../assets/img_bg_2.jpg";
import img3 from "../assets/img_bg_3.jpg";
import img4 from "../assets/img_bg_4.jpg";
const Carousel = () => {
  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 1000,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  };

  const slides = [
    { image: banner, caption: "First showcase for architecture" },
    { image: img2, caption: "Best showcase for architecture" },
    { image: img3, caption: "Best showcase for architecture" },
    { image: img4, caption: "Best showcase for architecture" },
  ];

  return (
    <aside id="thehero">
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {slides.map((slide, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${slide.image})`,
              height: "70vh",
              backgroundSize: "cover",
              backgroundPosition: "center",
            }}
          >
            <div className="overlay"></div>
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="slider-text">
                <h1>
                  <a href="#">{slide.caption}</a>
                </h1>
                <h2>
                  Cool Stuff
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    j2tw.co
                  </a>
                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Slider>
    </aside>
  );
};

export default Carousel;


